# Installing Kubernetes on IPV6

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, calico

I am trying to install Kubernetes 1.14.3 on IPV6 environment.

I don't have any IPV4 interface on this environment , only IPV6.

I tried with p-lain kubeadm config file and it seems to work but when I try to apply the calico cni the calico-node keeps failing.

```
2019-07-28 07:15:26.714 [INFO][9] startup.go 331: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get https://[fd20::4001]:443/api/v1/nodes/foo: dial tcp [fd20::4001]:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

this is the status og the pods at the moment:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE     IP                   NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-6894d6f4f4-hwsmc   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          79s     <none>               master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-fj8q7                          0/1     Running             1          79s     2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-8b995                    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5m53s   <none>               master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-fbpwq                    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5m53s   <none>               master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-master-eran                           1/1     Running             0          4m56s   2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master-eran                 1/1     Running             0          4m53s   2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master-eran        1/1     Running             0          5m7s    2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-4qzb8                           1/1     Running             0          5m53s   2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master-eran                 1/1     Running             0          4m50s   2001:df0:8800:4::7   master-eran   <none>           <none>
```

I guess that the codedns and controller will start only after the calico-node will run but it keeps failing on the error I pasted earlier.

in the kubeadm config file I chose ipvs in proxy configurations.

does any one have any idea on how to solve this?
thanks

NEW STATUS: 
I was able to resOlve the calico-node issue but now I am failing on calico-controller :

```
7-30 07:58:22.979 [ERROR][1] client.go 255: Error getting cluster information config ClusterInformation="default" error=Get https://[fd20::4001]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: dial tcp [fd20::4001]:443: connect: permission denied
2019-07-30 07:58:22.979 [FATAL][1] main.go 118: Failed to initialize Calico datastore error=Get https://[fd20::4001]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: dial tcp [fd20::4001]:443: connect: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Calico documentation you may need to perform a few additional steps before you can start using it with ipv6 only. About **enabling IPv6 with Kubernetes** you can read [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/ipv6#enabling-ipv6-with-kubernetes).

Comment: There isn't a link I haven't explored. none of them help. currently I was able to solve the calico-node issue but I am failing on calico-controller permissions to service-ip. I check my RBAC and they seems correct and it still fails

Comment: Please check if this is not the issue in your case too https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2191

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I actually gave up on IPV6 for K86 since I also found on open defect related to kube-proxy on ipvs mode.

Comment: Could you post a link documenting the issue with kube-proxy you came across ? It might be helpful for other community members dealing with similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: @mario were u able to install ipv6 support on it